# Why does xcopy behave strange in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, xcopy

I am working on Windows. I have a directory structure like the following:

- source

  - anotherFolder
  - folder

    - subFolder

      - 1.txt
    - 1.txt
    - 1.bak
- destination

  - folder
- Makefile

In the makefile I want to copy the directory structure and the .txt files from `source\folder` to `destination\folder`. I am using GNU make. The Makefile looks like this:

```
target:
    xcopy source\folder\*.txt destination\folder /s /e /y
```

When I execute the same command line on the shell it works. But from the makefile it doesn't copy any file and copies the directory structure of `source` instead of `source\folder`. The result looks like this:

- source

  - anotherFolder
  - folder

    - subFolder

      - 1.txt
    - 1.txt
    - 1.bak
- destination

  - folder

    - anotherFolder
    - folder

      - subFolder
- Makefile

If I add quotes around the paths in the command line, it works:

```
target:
    xcopy "source\folder\*.txt" "destination\folder" /s /e /y
```

But why? What is the difference?

Comment: If you do an `which xcopy` from both your shell and from make, do they return the same thing?   It doesn't explain the symptoms you're seeing, but it may explain why you're seeing different things between the make and the shell...  (the other variable is the shell itself -- make uses `sh` by default, though I don't see how that would change things in your particular case)

Comment: @HardcoreHenry, `where xcopy` returns `C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe` both from the shell and from the makefile.